# Python sort by two element, where it may be at any index / reversed

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list by two element, where element A or element B may be needed to sort by reverse.

My itemList is the following:

```
itemList = [['Inspiron 7559', 'Dell', 15.6, 3600, 4200],
 ['Latitude 7156', 'Dell', 14, 3600, 2150],
 ['Chromebook', 'Google', 14, 2500, 2600],
 ['MacBook Pro', 'Apple', 14, 2500, 6000],
 ['M17', 'Alienware', 15.6, 3600, 11250]]
```

I am expecting after I sort by this following, it produces

```
sortedList = sorted(itemList, key = lambda y: (-y[3], y[4]))

[['Latitude 7156', 'Dell', 14, 3600, 2150],
 ['Inspiron 7559', 'Dell', 15.6, 3600, 4200],
 ['M17', 'Alienware', 15.6, 3600, 11250],
 ['Chromebook', 'Google', 14, 2500, 2600],
 ['MacBook Pro', 'Apple', 14, 2500, 6000]]
```

However, my -y[3] and y[4] is not fixed, what I've had in my mind is declaring -y[3] and y[4] as varaible

input[0] is '-y[3]' and input[1] is 'y[4]'

```
y1 = input[0]
y2 = input[1]

sortedList = sorted(itemList, key = lambda y: (y1, y2))

[['Inspiron 7559', 'Dell', 15.6, 3600, 4200],
 ['Latitude 7156', 'Dell', 14, 3600, 2150],
 ['Chromebook', 'Google', 14, 2500, 2600],
 ['MacBook Pro', 'Apple', 14, 2500, 6000],
 ['M17', 'Alienware', 15.6, 3600, 11250]]
```

However, I find it is not sorting my items, I suspect because it is sorting as below:

```
sortedList = sorted(itemList, key = lambda y: ('-y[3]', 'y[4]'))
```

Is there any workarounds or I should use a different way?

Comment: `y1` and `y2` never appear to change for any element, so the sort will consider all elements equal. Please show a [mcve] and show your input and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to input the indices "3" and "4" and then use that to index `y` in the sort key?

Comment: @cs95 yes, but there may be a '-' key needed on the sorting (to reverse)
I've tried declaring a = 3, a1 = '-', b = 4, b2 = '' (empty), and resort by sortedList = sorted(itemList, key = lambda y: (a1+y[a], b2+y[b])), however it turns out I would need to convert everything to string, hence the same output

Comment: Try declaring `a=3, a_ascending=False, b=4, b_ascending=True`, now you should be able to do something like `key=lambda y: (y[a] * (1 if a_ascending else -1), y[b] * (1 if b_ascending else -1))`

Comment: @cs95 it worked out! thank you!

Comment: All good friend.